# Loop on several variables with the same suffix in R

Tags: r, function, loops

I have a database which looks like this but with much more rows and columns.

Several variables (x,y,z) measured at different time (1,2,3).

```
df <-
  tibble(
    x1 = rnorm(10),
    x2 = rnorm(10),
    x3 = rnorm(10),
    y1 = rnorm(10),
    y2 = rnorm(10),
    y3 = rnorm(10),
    z1 = rnorm(10),
    z2 = rnorm(10),
    z3 = rnorm(10),
  )
```

I am trying to create dummies variables from the variables with the same suffix (measured at the same time) like this:

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(var1= ifelse(x1>0 & (y1<0.5 |z1<0.5),0,1)) %>% 
  mutate(var2= ifelse(x2>0 & (y2<0.5 |z2<0.5),0,1)) %>%
  mutate(var3= ifelse(x3>0 & (y1<0.5 |z3<0.5),0,1))
```

I am used to coding in SAS or Stata, so I would like to use a function or a loop because I have many more variables in my database.
But I think I don't have the right approach in R to deal with this.

Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: Looks like unnormalized data. Start with `tidyr::pivot_longer`

Answer (score 0):

{dplyover} makes this kind of operation easy (disclaimer: I'm the maintainer), given that your desired output contains a typo:

I think you want to use all variables with the same digit (1, 2, 3 and so on) in each calculation:

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(var1= ifelse(x1>0 & (y1<0.5 |z1<0.5),0,1)) %>% 
  mutate(var2= ifelse(x2>0 & (y2<0.5 |z2<0.5),0,1)) %>%
  mutate(var3= ifelse(x3>0 & (y3<0.5 |z3<0.5),0,1))
```

If that is the case we can use `dplyover::over` to apply the same function over a vector. Here we construct the vector with `extract_names("[0-9]{1}$")` which gets us all ending numbers of our variable names here: `c(1,2,3)`. We can then construct the variable names using a special syntax: `.("x{.x}")`. Here `.x` evaluates to the first number in our vector so it would return the object name `x1` (not a string!) which we can use inside the function argument of `over`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(dplyover) # Only on GitHub: https://github.com/TimTeaFan/dplyover

df %>% 
  mutate(over(cut_names("^[a-z]{1}"),
              ~ ifelse(.("x{.x}") > 0 & (.("y{.x}") < 0.5 | .("z{.x}") < 0.5), 0, 1),
              .names = "var{x}"
              ))

#> # A tibble: 10 x 12
#>        x1      x2      x3      y1     y2     y3     z1     z2       z3  var1
#>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1  0.690  0.550   0.911   0.203  -0.111  0.530 -2.09   0.189  0.147       0
#>  2 -0.238  1.32   -0.145   0.744   1.05  -0.448  2.05  -1.04   1.50        1
#>  3  0.888  0.898  -1.46   -1.87   -1.14   1.59   1.91  -0.155  1.46        0
#>  4 -2.78  -1.34   -0.486  -0.0674  0.246  0.141  0.154  1.08  -0.319       1
#>  5 -1.20   0.835   1.28   -1.32   -0.674  0.115  0.362  1.06   0.515       1
#>  6  0.622 -0.713   0.0525  1.79   -0.427  0.819 -1.53  -0.885  0.00237     0
#>  7 -2.54   0.0197  0.942   0.230  -1.37  -1.02  -1.55  -0.721 -1.06        1
#>  8 -0.434  1.97   -0.274   0.848  -0.482 -0.422  0.197  0.497 -0.600       1
#>  9 -0.316 -0.219   0.467  -1.97   -0.718 -0.442 -1.39  -0.877  1.52        1
#> 10 -1.03   0.226   2.04    0.432  -1.02  -0.535  0.954 -1.11   0.804       1
#> # ... with 2 more variables: var2 <dbl>, var3 <dbl>
```

Alternatively we can use `dplyr::across` and use `cur_column()`, `get()` and `gsub()` to alter the name of the column on the fly. To name the new variables correctly we use `gsub()` in the `.names` argument of `across` and wrap it in curly braces `{}` to evaluate the expression.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("x"),
                ~ {
                  cur_c <- dplyr::cur_column()
                  ifelse(.x > 0 & (get(gsub("x","y", cur_c)) < 0.5 | get(gsub("x","z", cur_c)) < 0.5), 0, 1)
                },
                .names = '{gsub("x", "var", .col)}'
                ))

#> # A tibble: 10 x 12
#>         x1      x2     x3     y1      y2     y3      z1      z2      z3  var1
#>      <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 -0.423  -1.42   -1.15  -1.54   1.92   -0.511 -0.739   0.501   0.451      1
#>  2 -0.358   0.164   0.971 -1.61   1.96   -0.675 -0.0188 -1.88    1.63       1
#>  3 -0.453  -0.758  -0.258 -0.449 -0.795  -0.362 -1.81   -0.780  -1.90       1
#>  4  0.855   0.335  -1.36   0.796 -0.674  -1.37  -1.42   -1.03   -0.560      0
#>  5  0.436  -0.0487 -0.639  0.352 -0.325  -0.893 -0.746   0.0548 -0.394      0
#>  6 -0.228  -0.240  -0.854 -0.197  0.884   0.118 -0.0713  1.09   -0.0289     1
#>  7 -0.949  -0.231   0.428  0.290 -0.803   2.15  -1.11   -0.202  -1.21       1
#>  8  1.88   -0.0980 -2.60  -1.86  -0.0258 -0.965 -1.52   -0.539   0.108      0
#>  9  0.221   1.58   -1.46  -0.806  0.749   0.506  1.09    0.523   1.86       0
#> 10  0.0238 -0.389  -0.474  0.512 -0.448   0.178  0.529   1.56   -1.12       1
#> # ... with 2 more variables: var2 <dbl>, var3 <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You could restructure your data along the principles of tidy data (see e.g. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html).

Here to a long format and using `tidyverse`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <-
  df |>
  pivot_longer(everything()) |>
  separate(name, c("var", "time"), sep = "(?=[0-9])") |>
  pivot_wider(id_col = "time",
              names_from = "var",
              names_prefix = "var_",
              values_from = "value",
              values_fn = list) |>
  unnest(-time) |>
  mutate(new_var = ifelse(var_x > 0 & (var_y < 0.5 | var_z < 0.5), 0, 1))

  df
```

**You would probably want to keep the data in a long format**, but if you want, you can `pivot_wider` and get back to the format you started with. E.g.

```r
df |>
  pivot_wider(values_from = c(starts_with("var_"), "new_var"),
              names_from = "time",
              values_fn = list) |> 
  unnest(everything())
```

Answer (score 0):

As you suggested, a solution using a loop is definitely possible.

```r
# times as unique non-alphabetical parts of column names
times <- unique(gsub('[[:alpha:]]', '', names(df)))
for (time in times) {
  
  # column names for current time
  xyz <- paste0(c('x', 'y', 'z'), time)
  df[[paste0('var', time)]] <- 
    ifelse(df[[xyz[1]]]>0 & (df[[xyz[2]]]<.5 | df[[xyz[3]]]<.5), 0, 1)
}
```

Another way I can think of is transforming the data into a 3D array (observartion × variable × time) so that you can actually do the computation for all variables at once.

```r
times <- unique(gsub('[[:alpha:]]', '', names(df)))
df.arr <- sapply(c('x', 'y', 'z'), 
                 function(var) as.matrix(df[, paste0(var, times)]), 
                 simplify='array')
new.vars <- ifelse(df.arr[, , 1]>0 & (df.arr[, , 2]<0.5 | df.arr[, , 3]<0.5), 0, 1)
colnames(new.vars) <- paste0('var', times)
cbind(df, new.vars)
```

Here, `sapply` creates a matrix from columns of measurings for each variable at different times and stacks them into a 3D array.

If you trust (or ensure) correct ordering of columns in the data frame, instead of using `sapply` you can create the array just by modifying the object's dimensions. I didn't do any benchmarking but i guess this could be the most computationally efficient solution (if it should matter).

```r
df.arr <- as.matrix(df)
dim(df.arr) <- c(dim(df.arr) / c(1, 3), 3)
```